# A question on forms

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $d<\infty$, and let $v\in V\setminus\{0\}$. 
Let $f\in \Lambda^p V$ be such that $v\wedge f=0$. 
I want to show that there exists a $g\in \Lambda^{p-1}V$ such that $f=v\wedge g$.

My attempt: We can find a basis $\{e_1,\dots, e_d\}$ starting from $v=:e_1$. 
Let the dual basis be defined by $\{\epsilon^1,\dots, \epsilon^d\}$. 
My guess is to take 
$$
g(\tau^1,\dots,\tau^{p-1}):=f(\epsilon^1, \tau^1,\dots,\tau^{p-1}), \quad \tau^i\in V^*.
$$
Then clearly $g\in \Lambda^{p-1}V$, since swapping any two $\tau^i$s creates a sign change, thanks to the skew-symmetry of $f$. I tried showing that the action of $f$ and of $v\wedge g$ is the same, but couldn't yet manage to show this using $v\wedge f=0$. I would be grateful for a hint or outline. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll fix the notation $v\in\Lambda^1V$, and $\mathcal{V}\in V$ for the vector corresponding to $v$ through a basis, inner product, or something else.
This is characterized by $v(\mathcal{V}) = 1$.

You've sorta discovered the [interior product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product) of forms with vector fields and have defined $g = \iota_\mathcal{V}(f)$.
Taking a look at the properties of the inner product at the previous hyperlink, we have

$$
\iota_\mathcal{V}(v\wedge f) = \iota_\mathcal{V}(v)\wedge f - v\wedge \iota_\mathcal{V}(f).
$$

Now, the result will follow from 
$$
\iota_\mathcal{V}(v) \wedge f= 1\wedge f = f
$$
and from the hypothesis $v\wedge f = 0$.